# Swapping two adjacent nodes singularly linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes

Hi I have a structure as follows

```
 struct node{
     struct node *next;
     char *item;
 };
```

and I'm trying to write a function swap two adjacent items (which I will then use to iterate through the linked list in main).

My function so far:

```
 void swap(struct node *n1, struct node *n2){
      if(strcmp(a,b) > 0){
          a->next = b->next;
          b->next = a;
```

Since the nodes contain data of varying length I have to swap the actual nodes rather than just the data and I'm stuck on how to do that.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have parsed your linked list the way to swap the nodes is by considering also the previous nodes that linked to your two candidates. But there won't be a previous node if it is the first item in the list, and it can get complicated. So swap the data pointers. In your example, the node struct contains only a string pointer. So swap the string pointers. If there is a massive amount of data in the your actual node struct, make a copy of the `next` pointers, swap the structs, and replace the next pointers.

```
char *tempp = n1->item;
n1->item = n2->item;
n2->item = tempp;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void swap(struct node **n1, struct node **n2)
{ 
// Initialize previous and current pointers
struct node *node1 = *n1;
struct node *node2 = *n2;
struct node *temp;
temp = node2->next;
node2->next = node1;
node1->next = temp;
}
```

You can also use the below code so that there are no extra nodes added:

```
void swap(struct node **n1, struct node **n2){
(*n1) = (int)(*n1)^(int)(*n2);
(*n2) = (int)(*n1)^(int)(*n2);
(*n1) = (int)(*n1)^(int)(*n2);
}
```